# How do I make the scoreboard show in color?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map, and I'm using the scoreboard, but I want it to show to first name/score to be maybe green and then the last ones to be a player name.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text in Minecraft can be formatted with the section sign (§). In normal gameplay, the section sign can only be entered into Book and Quills. However, external programs can be used to insert it in other locations.

Messages sent from the server to the client can contain color codes, which allow coloring of text for various purposes.

A section sign (§) followed by a hex digit in the message tells the client to switch colors while displaying text.

Visit this site to see the full article: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes

Comment: I need a way to do it inside Minecraft without external programmes I just want to do it using Command Blocks.

Comment: Then use .json strings. `{text:"Scoreboard",color:"red"}`

Comment: So /scoreboard objectives add {text:"Kills",color:"red"} totalKillCount Kills